# Simple gui that display a repeated set of images when a button is pushed

Tags: python, user-interface, module, tkinter

I made a very simple gui that has a button and shows an image(.gif). My goal is to output another .gif whenever you press the button. There are 2 .gif files in my file directory and the point is to keep switching between these two whenever you press the button.

```
#Using python2.7.2
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

try:
    n
except:
    n = 0

def showphoto(par):
    if par%2 == 0:
        try:
            label2.destroy()
        except:
            pass
        photo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="masc.gif")
        label2 = Tkinter.Label(image=photo)
        label2.image = photo
        label2.pack()

    else:
        try:
            label2.destroy()
        except: 
            pass
        photo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="123.gif")
        label2 = Tkinter.Label(image=photo)
        label2.image = photo
        label2.pack()

myContainer1 = Tkinter.Frame(root, width = 100, height = 100)
myContainer1.pack()

def callback(event):
    global n
    showphoto(n)
    n = n + 1

button1 = Tkinter.Button(myContainer1)
button1["text"]= "Next pic" 
button1["background"] = "green"
button1.bind("<Button-1>", callback(n))     
button1.pack()                 

root.mainloop()
```

The current code just outputs the first image (`masc.gif`) but when I press the button it doesn't switch to the other image(`123.gif`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think with this code you simply need to make n global outside of the callback. Instead of `try: n; except: n = 0`, why not use `global n; n = 0`?

Comment: I did this and it doesn't change anything. Also, as far as I know, declaring a variable global outside of a function is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

This can achieved much easier with classes as the class holds all the data necessary without the use of global variables.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from collections import OrderedDict

class app(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,master=None, **kwargs):
      self.gifdict=OrderedDict()
      for gif in ('masc.gif','123.gif'):
          self.gifdict[gif]=tk.PhotoImage(file=gif)
      tk.Frame.__init__(self,master,**kwargs)
      self.label=tk.Label(self)
      self.label.pack()
      self.button=tk.Button(self,text="switch",command=self.switch)
      self.button.pack()
      self.switch()  

   def switch(self):
      #Get first image in dict and add it to the end
      img,photo=self.gifdict.popitem(last=False)
      self.gifdict[img]=photo
      #display the image we popped off the start of the dict.
      self.label.config(image=photo)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
   A=tk.Tk()
   B=app(master=A,width=100,height=100)
   B.pack()
   A.mainloop()
```

Of course, this could be done more generally ... (the list of images to cycle through could be passed in for example), and this will switch through all the images in self.gifs ...

This approach also removes the necessity to destroy and recreate a label each time, instead we just reuse the label we already have.

**EDIT**

Now I use an OrderedDict to store the files.  (keys=filename,values=PhotoImages).  Then we pop the first element out of the dictionary to plot.  Of course, if you're using python2.6 or earlier, you can just keep a list in addition to the dictionary and use the list to get the keys.

Comment: This version leaks memory -- every time you switch you create another image. Instead, create the image and store it in a dict. The next time you switch, check the dict and use the already-created image if it exists. You could also remove that confusing index calculation by simply pulling the image from the front of the list and adding it to the end.

Comment: @BryanOakley -- did it actually leak memory?  While it's true that it did create a new photoimage every time you switch, the old one should have been garbage collected (I thought...)  Anyway, changing the order of the list is a good idea (as was the dict) so I edited.  The only downside with this is that you need to have enough memory to store the entire sequence of gifs in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
button1 = Tkinter.Button(myContainer1)
button1["text"]= "Next pic" 
button1["background"] = "green"
button1.bind("<Button-1>", callback(n))
```

First, you bind the `<Button-1>` event to `None` (that's what `callback(n)` evaluates to). You should bind it to `callback` (no parentheses a.k.a the call operator).

Second, I suggest you change `callback` to not accept any arguments, remove the `bind` call and create your button as:

```
button1 = Tkinter.Button(myContainer1, command=callback)
```